# Lilypond - Convert number to markup

Tags: lilypond

I would like to create a shorthand for a compound markup command, say MVE

`#(define-markup-command (shorthand layout props text) (number-or-markup?) (interpret-markup layout props #{ \markup \bold \italic #text #}))`

However, this errors out with "error: not a markup" when passed a number. How would I type-coerce the argument into markup?

- Adding a nested `\markup` is "unexpected".
- `\simple` only takes strings to begin with.
- Yes I know passing `"number"` avoids the issue but it's not ergonomic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, instead of `#text` you could write `#(if (number? text) (number->string text) text)`.  The obvious idea `#(format #f "~a" text)` would fail if text happened to be a markup that isn't a string.

Answer (score 1):

Based on **user73384** finding the core conversion function (`number->string`), I'm using

`#(define-markup-command (to-markup layout props text) (number-or-markup?) (interpret-markup layout props #{ #(if (number? text) (number->string text) text) #}))`

as a helper.